# One particular property is returned null from a web service when using an android simulator

Tags: web-services, xamarin, inheritance, deserialization

I designed a web service function that returns an object. One string property of the object has value when I call the web service's function in UWP. But that particular property is always **null** when I call the function with the same parameters from the **Xamarin** project even though the other properties have the right values.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! Can you share your function or some code as we could help you?

Comment: It would be good to post the code but it is rather complicated and it will take a long time to sift it out. When I do more tests, I realized than changing the order of the properties in the resulting posted object changes the result. Is there any known bugs in the deserialization process used in Android emulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It arises when the return object is derived from some other object. The properties of the scaffolded reference derived class get **Order** attributes in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute which overlaps with the order attributes of the base class.
UWP handles the situation seamlessly but Xamarin Android cannot! You may think to flag your properties in the web service so that their orders will not overlap, but no.. Unfortunately, scaffolding overrides any decoration hint you provide. The only way I can find is to flatten the hierarchy. I just put all the base class properties to the class and removed the inheritance. 
I was lucky to have the source code of the web service but it will not be always the case. I think it is a **serious** bug to be escalated because Xamarin apps may need to support some old-fashioned services.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)